# objetos y arrays en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Estoy aprendiendo javascript y me encontre con este ejercicio:

**"Hacer una función que reciba un objeto y retorne un array con todos los valores de sus propiedades cómo elementos. Ejemplo:**

```
console.log(aArrayDeValores({ a: 1, b: "z", c: 3})); // imprime [1, "z",3]

console.log(aArrayDeValores({ a: "f", b: true})); // imprime ["f", true]"
```

Se como hacerlo con un objeto en especifico, es decir conociendo sus propiedades de antemano, pero no se como hacerlo para cualquier objeto que reciba la funcion como argumento. Alguien me podria ayudar?

Comment: Lectura recomendada: [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

Answer (score 0):

Con la función:

```
Object.values(objectToGetValues)
```

Consigues todos los valores de un objeto. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
function printValues(objectGetValues) {
    return Object.values(objectGetValues)
}

const testOne = {a: 1, b: "z", c: 3}
const testTwo = {a: "f", b: true}

console.log(printValues(testOne)) // [1, 'z', 3]
console.log(printValues(testTwo)) // ['f', true]
```